# Как сбросить программу Python в начальное состояние?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу программу на Python 3.9 с графическим интерфейсом. Используются различные модули (PyQt5, PyGame, MoviePy и другие...)
Появилась необходимость сбрасывать программу к начальному состоянию.
**Есть какая либо простая функция для таких задач?**
Что-нибудь вроде рестарта программы или переинициализации... что-бы не чистить циклами массивы, объекты и т.п. так как их достаточно много.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11329917/7485582

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]